# Lambda Resource in CloudFormation Template Reports CodeUri as Invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Given the following CloudFormation template snippet:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  PrototypeCreateOrderFDM4:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      CodeUri: "../Lambda/"
      Handler: "PrototypeCreateOrder.handler"
      Timeout: 15
      Runtime: "nodejs10.x"
      Role: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/deezNutz-Role-1ABC8DDEFGHI
```

I'm getting a warning saying that the CodeURI isn't a valid property:

[image]

I have lots of other Lambda's structure like this. I've never gotten this before. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the [`AWS::Lambda::Function` resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html), which doesn't have a CodeUri property.

You're probably thinking of the [`AWS::Serverless::Function` from SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-template.html#serverless-sam-template-function), which supports a CodeUri property.

However, with SAM, you can omit the CodeUri property if your Lambda code is local to your template (and if your handler is under `Lambda/index.js`, then you can just point the `Handler:` property to the path directly). Can't say for sure if this will work with `AWS::Lambda::Function`, but will definitely with SAM's `AWS::Serverless::Function`.